# Loop through an object and only return certain keys together with their values

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Given the following object, how can I loop through this object inorder to obtain both keys and values but only for the following keys:

```
    "myName": "Demo"
    "active": "Y"
    "myCode": "123456789"
    "myType": 1


let a = {
    "values": {
        "myName": "Demo",
        "active": "Y",
        "myCode": "123456789",
        "myType": 1,
        "myGroups": [
            {
                "myGroupName": "Group 1",
                "myTypes": [
                    {
                        "myTypeName": "323232",
                        "myTypeId": "1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "myGroupName": "Group 2",
                "myTypes": [
                    {
                        "myTypeName": "523232",
                        "myTypeId": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(a.values)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
For}
```

but this will return all keys with their values.

Comment: The selected answer for this question is not performant as it iterates over the entire entrified-object. It would be more perfomant to loop over only the dictionary array and using those values to check the original object. This would also save you time from having to convert the object to an array via `Object.entries()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary (array) to contain the keys you want to extract the properties for, and then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the values with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to produce a new object matching only those entries [`included`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in the dictionary.

```js
let a = {
  "values": {
    "myName": "Demo",
    "active": "Y",
    "myCode": "123456789",
    "myType": 1,
    "myGroups": [{
        "myGroupName": "Group 1",
        "myTypes": [{
          "myTypeName": "323232",
          "myTypeId": "1"
        }]
      },
      {
        "myGroupName": "Group 2",
        "myTypes": [{
          "myTypeName": "523232",
          "myTypeId": "2"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}

const arr = [ 'myName', 'active', 'myCode', 'myType' ];

const out = Object.entries(a.values).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if (arr.includes(key)) acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Just what I was after.

Comment: The downside of this answer is that it iterates over the entire entrified-object. You would be better off looping over **only** the dictionary array and using those values to check the original object. This also saves you time from having to convert the object to an array via `Object.entries()`.

Answer (score -1):

The best answer would be to set up an array of the desired keys and then iterate over **that** array instead of an array of the original object's entries. This is how you would achieve that:

```js
let a = {
  values: {
    myName: "Demo",
    active: "Y",
    myCode: "123456789",
    myType: 1,
    myGroups: [{
      myGroupName: "Group 1",
      myTypes: [{
        myTypeName: "323232",
        myTypeId: "1"
      }]
    }, {
      myGroupName: "Group 2",
      myTypes: [{
        myTypeName: "523232",
        myTypeId: "2"
      }]
    }]
  }
};

const keys = ['myName', 'active', 'myCode', 'myType'];

const cherryPick = (obj, keys) => keys.reduce((a,c) => (a[c] = obj[c], a), {});

console.log(cherryPick(a.values, keys));
```

The above example will work for many provided keys. If a key does not exist in the supplied object, its value will be undefined. If you want to only keep properties which have values, simply add an optional filter to the `cherryPick()` function, like this:

```js
let test = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};

const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const cherryPick = (obj, keys, filter = 0) => keys.filter(key => filter ? obj[key] : 1).reduce((acc,key) => (acc[key] = obj[key], acc), {});

console.log('STORE undefined :: cherryPick(test, keys)', cherryPick(test, keys));
console.log('FILTER undefined :: cherryPick(test, keys, 1)', cherryPick(test, keys, true));
```

```css
/* Ignore this */ .as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```